# Facing 'Subscription validation request timed out' Issue with Microsoft Graph Notifications

Tags: laravel, notifications, microsoft-graph-api, webhooks, ngrok

I am currently working on integrating Microsoft Graph notifications into my application and have encountered an issue that I am seeking help with. I've provided a detailed breakdown of my setup and the problem below, and any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Problem Overview:**

I am using ngrok to expose my local server to the internet, and I'm attempting to subscribe to Microsoft Graph notifications for changes in a user's mailbox. However, I am consistently receiving the following error when trying to create a subscription:

```
{
    "error": "Failed to create subscription",
    "details": {
        "error": {
            "code": "InvalidRequest",
            "message": "Subscription validation request timed out.",
            "innerError": {
                "date": "2023-12-14T11:08:13",
                "request-id": "xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx",
                "client-request-id": "xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Configuration:**

- Laravel backend with ngrok for local server exposure.
- Microsoft Graph API v1.0.
- Authentication using JWT tokens.
- Subscription endpoint: https://5539-202-168-72-145.ngrok-free.app/graph-notifications.
- Expiration time for subscription set to 1 day.

**Controller Methods:**

```
public function subscribe()
    {
        $user = JWTAuth::toUser();

        if (!$user) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'User not authenticated']);
        }

        $accessToken = $user->ms_access_token;

        if (!$accessToken) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Access token not set for user']);
        }

        $notificationEndpoint = 'https://5539-202-168-72-145.ngrok-free.app/graph-notifications';

        $graphApiEndpoint = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/';

        $state = str_random(32);

        $subscriptionUrl = $graphApiEndpoint . 'subscriptions';

        $expirationDateTime = now()->addDays(1)->toISOString();

        $subscriptionResponse = Http::withHeaders([
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ])->post($subscriptionUrl, [
            'changeType' => 'created,updated,deleted',
            'notificationUrl' => $notificationEndpoint,
            'resource' => "/me/mailfolders('inbox')/messages",
            'expirationDateTime' => $expirationDateTime,
            'clientState' => $state,
        ]);

        if (!$subscriptionResponse->successful()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Failed to create subscription', 'details' => $subscriptionResponse->json()], $subscriptionResponse->status());
        }

        $subscriptionId = optional(json_decode($subscriptionResponse->getBody()))->id;

        if (!$subscriptionId) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Subscription ID not found in the response']);
        }
        return response()->json(['subscriptionId' => $subscriptionId]);
    }

    public function handleNotifications(Request $request)
    {
        \Log::debug("message from handleNotifications", $request->toArray());

        $validationToken = $request->query('validationToken');

        if ($validationToken) {
            return response($validationToken, 200)->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8');
        }

        return response('Invalid request', 400)->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    }
```

**Routes:**

```
Route::post('/graph-notifications', [MicrosoftGraphApiController::class, 'handleNotifications']);
Route::get('/graph-subscribe', [MicrosoftGraphApiController::class, 'subscribe']); (Wrapped in middleware)
```

**Log output:**

`development.DEBUG: message from handleNotifications {"validationToken":"Validation: Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: xxxxxxx-xxxx-4510-81a8-xxxxxxxxx"}`

**Additional Information:**

- The ngrok URL is correctly formatted with HTTPS.
- Subscription creation includes necessary headers and parameters.
- The ngrok URL can be pinged successfully.
- I've tested the ngrok URL with a simple endpoint and it works as expected.

**Seeking Help:**

I am seeking the community's help to understand why the subscription validation request is timing out. What steps can I take to troubleshoot this issue? Are there any additional configurations or checks that I might be missing?

Any guidance, insights, or experiences related to Microsoft Graph subscriptions and ngrok would be immensely helpful. Thank you in advance!